# Installing a software from Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to develop a program using Xcode on macOS.

The program compiles and links fine, but when trying to execute it, I get an error message stating that a library can't be found in "/usr/local/lib".

The library in question is actually developed by myself, and is part of the project bundle.

How can I install my program in order to test it inside Xcode?

Comment: Can you detail which library it is that it cannot find?

Comment: Yeah. If you don’t build in Xcode, just open the inspector once you have a program running and attach to that process. If your software is built from the command line, use a command line debugger. You might need a second question or to edit this based on what you seek to do.

Comment: @jksoegaard, question updated with explanation.

Comment: @bmike Your answer has no relation whatsoever to the question. This is not about inspectors or debuggers at all.

Comment: You might be right @jksoegaard - that’s why I didn’t answer and commented to seek clarification. In my mind it was 50/50 chance the “build” was in Xcode or not. The whole “install my program” has me quite confused what’s actually going on. +1 for the efforts and comments

Comment: It doesn’t matter if the build is in Xcode or not. Using a debugger or a profiler requires you to be able to run the program. He’s not able to run the program. So he needs to fix that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such "install" function in Xcode.

If your program needs a library in order to run, you'll need to either bundle the library with the program or create an installer that copies the library and your application into place.

You can bundle the library with the program by statically linking (effectively not having a library at runtime) - or by embedding. Embedded is explained by Apple here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html

Usually on development machines, you install internal dependencies such as libraries through the use of build scripts or build steps addded in Xcode. You could simply add a new Build Phase (named "Copy Library" or similar) - and then add a Copy Files step, where you copy your .dylib (or .so or whatever) to the intended destination.

Comment: @ksoegaard, the thing is that the library the linker is looking for is part of my project. So definitly HomeBrew is not work work here. And I'm not sure about the other option...

Comment: @Igor Okay, that was not part of your question before - I'll update the answer!

Comment: @ksoegaard, are you saying that during the development I should create the new "Build Phase" and when its ready for release I should embed the library as explained in the link you posted? Also, does this link explains how to create this extra "Build Phase" and what to put in it or it talks only about embedding? Sorry I'm new to Apple development

Comment: If you're not going to embed a framework, then create a manual build phase or build script for copying over the file to /usr/local/lib or whereever you need it. If you're going to embed the framework, that's not needed as the file needs to be placed within your app folder. The link only explains how to embed, not the build phase - I explained that in the answer.

Comment: Please also understand that this is not something special for "Apple development". It is the same on Linux. On Linux you usually include the copying of the library in a Makefile (i.e. the same as adding a Build Phase), or your statically link or otherwise embed the library.

Comment: @ksoegaard, OK, I think I added such build phase. But now trying to build I received an error: `error: couldn't create directory /usr/local/lib: Permission denied`. Now I know on *nix you run the install script as root. So what should I do with Xcode on OSX? Please advise. TIA!

Comment: It’s the same on Linux as on macOS. Never run builds scripts as root. Use sudo to install.

Comment: @ksoegaard, right. But in Xcode I just hit `Command+B` and it runs the build. And in the end I am receiving the error like above as part of the build process. Whereas in *nix I build and then I run "sudo make install" to install it - 2 way process.

Comment: @Igor Please understand that macOS is also a Unix. There’s really no difference. You can just use make and make install on macOS the same way as on Linux. You can just use sudo within your build steps in Xcode. Please check the docs for help on creating new build steps, or ask a separate question on that.

Comment: I understand that OSX is a *nix. But the process of building and running the application is different in both systems. I will ask another question to clarify. Thx. I also upvoted and accepted the answer.

Comment: New question is created here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362062/how-to-run-the-build-phase-in-xcode-as-root